# facebook sdk getuser() always return 0 after login?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below is my controller. I am trying to login using facebook php sdk. In it `getuser()` function always return 0 after login.  What is the problem?

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_Authentication extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Load user model
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

    public function index(){

       // Include the facebook api php libraries
        include_once APPPATH."libraries/facebook-api-php-codexworld/facebook.php";

        // Facebook API Configuration
        $appId = '1863771173889202';
        $appSecret = 'e86b25ccab12bc88c46aac322ebc40eb';
        $redirectUrl = base_url() . 'user_authentication/';
        $fbPermissions = 'email';

        //Call Facebook API
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $appId,
          'secret' => $appSecret

        ));
        $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($fbuser) {
            $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
            // Preparing data for database insertion
            $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
            $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
            $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
            $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
            $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
            $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
            $userData['profile_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$userProfile['id'];
            $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture']['data']['url'];
            // Insert or update user data
            $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
            if(!empty($userID)){
                $data['userData'] = $userData;
                $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
            } else {
               $data['userData'] = array();
            }
        } else {
            $fbuser = '';
            $data['authUrl'] = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$redirectUrl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
        }
        $this->load->view('user_authentication/index',$data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('userData');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/user_authentication');
    }
}
```

I am a beginner here so please help me resolve my issue.

Comment: What is the error `getUser` function is throwing? Reason can be anything, permissions, incorrect access token, etc.

Comment: Updated title, grammar, and text for readability

Comment: its not giving any error after login it redirect me to login page again

Comment: but now i have done it with different  way..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the **redirect_uri** and put the proper URL in it.
    Here is the line of code I thinks its help you:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array ( 
'display' => 'popup',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/demo/index.php'
));
```

Comment: its not hepling.. getuser() return 0 after login.i set redirect uri http://loclhost/fblogin/

Comment: Please check this setting also go to  base_facebook.php file, find the makeRequest() method and check for following Line.

        $opts = self::$CURL_OPTS; 
        
        if you got the line please add this line,
        $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

Answer (score 0):

In window.fbAsyncInit I have set cookie and oauth to true and this worked!

cookie:true,
oauth : true.

Make sure that In your php you also have

cookie' => true.

That will enable the php code to integrare with the JS.

And you need to make sure the user has logged in with:

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'read_stream,etc..'));

The scope is defined by the permissions stated here

After that you should be able to do:

$user = $facebook->api("/me");

Which will get an array associated with the user, $user['id'] is probably the one you'll want to store as well as any other information like email address - be sure to request for email in the scope

Hope that solves the problem!

Comment: window.fbAsyncInit i don't understand what is it mean

Comment: i mean in your php.ini file. You should go to php.ini file and update cookie to true and follow above code. Will work :)

Comment: which line i have to uncomment there are many places cookie write in php.ini file

Comment: GO to Application->config->config.php file. and make below changes: 
$config['cookie_secure'] = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = TRUE;

Comment: its not helping..i think a reason can be i m using php sdk3 not the latest version